# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended using offset and fetch next oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting an error when running the follow command

```
SELECT
*
FROM
tablename
ORDER BY
column OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

This is the error.

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 17
```

Will this be slow if using a very simple table with 1+ million rows for example?
If so why?
How do i make it faster?

Comment: My guess is that you are not really running 12C.  You can test using `select * from V$VERSION;`.

Comment: you are right lol 11g